# Training same model with different training data in RASA NLU

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

I have created a chatbot and added the training data(some hundred's) and trained it till now it's well and good. But when i added more training data some 50,000 and even more. Now, I'm stuck here RASA NLU unable to train that much amount of training data it can train upto 20,000 of training data but can't more than that.I'm getting "ERROR:Cannot allocate memory"

Answer (score 0):

You may have to prune your training set in order to leave room for the new examples.
You don't need to feed your model with all the combinations of possible words. It's good at generalizing even learning a sparse set of combinations.

As you're working with 50k examples, I imagine you're already using a tool to generate them. You may look in the docs if it can help you do the pruning, or switch to the currently [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50331593/1225667) one, that can.